# Problems with contains when using moq

Tags: c#, moq, equals, contains

I want to test a delete methode.
The delete methode is called in a mocked service (not mocked with moq).

The service manages a list of objects. The class of the objects is derived from a base class overriding equals().

```
 public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) {
            return false;
        }

        BaseClass testObj = (BaseClass)obj;
        return BusinessId.Equals(testObj.BusinessId);

    }
```

When I call

```
 serive.GetAll().Contains(objectInList);
```

I get false.

The Equals method in the base class is not called.
The objects in the list are mocked with moq.

```
 Mock<TypeOfObject> objectMock = new Mock<TypeOfObject>();
 objectMock.SetupGet(pf => pf.BusinessId).Returns(guid);
 return objectMock.Object;
```

How do I have to setup the mock that the Equals-Methode of the base class is called and the Contains-method returns true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wouldnt this work? objectMock .Setup(a => a.Equals("something")).Returns(true);

Comment: but then i always get true for equals and for contains?

Comment: @Tobias, don't forget to override `GetHashCode` along with `Equals`! It probably won't solve this very issue, but it might prevent more problems further down the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the mock to call your Equals method by settings Mock.CallBase property to true, e.g.:

```
Mock<TypeOfObject> objectMock = new Mock<TypeOfObject>();
objectMock.SetupGet(pf => pf.BusinessId).Returns(guid);
objectMock.CallBase = true;
return objectMock.Object;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because of your GetType() check. The object you're passing is a `Mock`, not `BaseClass`.

Try this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null && obj is BaseClass)
    {
        return BusinessId.Equals((obj as BaseClass).BusinessId);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this a lot, when you do an `is` check, why not just use the faster `(BaseClass)obj`, `as` can be thought of internally as doing the following: `obj is T? (T)obj : default(T)`. Thus it seems pointless to use an `as` inside of an `is`.

Comment: The explicit cast `(BaseClass)obj` throws an exception if the cast is not valid, whereas `is` and `as` don't.  But you can usually avoid doing both `is`+cast simply by doing (only) an `as` and checking for a `null` return.